# Generate HTML attributes automatically in MVC 3 depending on data type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following property in the MVC Model:

```
[Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The Volume must have positive values!")]       
public decimal? Volume { get; set; }
```

The generated HTML is

```
<input type="text" value="1,00" name="Product.Volume" id="Product_Volume" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-range-max="1.79769313486232E+308" data-val-range="The Volume must have positive values!" data-val-number="The field Volume must be a number." data-val="true" class="text-box single-line">
```

How do I make the generated HTML be something like this:

```
<input type="text" value="1,00" name="Product.Volume" id="Product_Volume" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-range-max="1.79769313486232E+308" data-val-range="The Volume must have positive values!" data-val-number="The field Volume must be a number." data-val="true" class="text-box single-line" data-type="decimal" >
```

The difference is the additional **`data-type="decimal"`**

I want the HTML attribute to be added **automatically**, so I do not have to manually add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was an override of HTML TextBoxFor helper Method:

```
        public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxWithCustomHtmlAttributesFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            Type propertyType = typeof(TProperty);
            Type undelyingNullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);
            var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
            string prefix = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            var validationAttributes = helper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(prefix, metadata);

            string pType = (undelyingNullableType ?? propertyType).Name.ToString().ToLower();
            if (htmlAttributes != null)
            {
                var dataTypeDict = new Dictionary<string, object>(); 
                dataTypeDict.Add("data-type", pType);
                if (validationAttributes != null && validationAttributes.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var i in validationAttributes)
                    {
                        dataTypeDict.Add(i.Key, i.Value);
                    }
                }
                htmlAttributes = Combine(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), new RouteValueDictionary(dataTypeDict));
            }
            var textBox = helper.TextBoxFor(expression, (Dictionary<string, object>)htmlAttributes);
            return textBox;
        }
```

Answer (score 10):

Create your own Display Template and Editor Template views for the `Decimal` type, that way you can control the display of it and then any Model property that is of type `Decimal` will automatically use that view whenever you call `Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DecimalType)` or `Html.EditorFor(m => m.DecimalType)`

Add these Views in the folders **Views > Shared > DisplayTemplates and EditorTemplates**

For example, your EditorTemplate would be something like:

```
@model decimal
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Template.cshtml";
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x, new {data-type = "decimal"})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I have to then create a search/replace everywhere ?

Also, what happens with the data-annotations I want to put manually ?

Comment: @DragosDurlut No problems, no you don't have to search/replace everywhere as your models will automatically pick up the templates for the given type `decimal`. Your other data-annotations should remain intact